# Why didn't Ella wonder how Lucifer survived gunshots in season 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

In season 3 Lucifer is going to help his ex-wife in Las Vegas (episode 6 or 7 I think). Ella joins him on this trip. In the last 10 min he gets shot multiple times by a guy. Ella is near Lucifer but cannot see him, she has to have heard the gunshots though.

Why does Ella later not wonder how Lucifer survived these shots? Did I miss something in the last season? Does Ella know he has superpowers or was this just an oversight from the writers/directors?

Comment: Did it mentioned that she assumed those shots were taken at Lucifer?